# Mocked HttpClientFactory returns null when creating client

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, asp.net-core-3.1, nsubstitute

I am trying to unit test a service that uses the `IHttpClientFactory` with Nunit and NSubstitute for mocking.

The service I want to test looks like this

```
public class Movies : IMovies
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public Movies(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    { 
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<MovieCollection> GetPopularMovies(int PageNumber = 1)
    {

        // Get an instance of HttpClient from the factpry that we registered
        // in Startup.cs
         var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("Movie Api");

        // Call the API & wait for response. 
        // If the API call fails, call it again according to the re-try policy
        // specified in Startup.cs
        var result =
            await client.GetAsync($"movie/popular?api_key=<the_api_key>language=en-US&page={PageNumber}");
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Read all of the response and deserialise it into an instace of

            var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MovieCollection>(content);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

When I run the test I get an error that says

> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>        at MovieApi.Services.Movies.GetPopularMovies(Int...

Here is the test I am running.The error occurs only when I put the keyword `await` in the line

```
var result = await service.GetPopularMovies(1);
```

Check the Test code below:

```
[Test]
public async Task GetPopular_WhenCalled_ReturnOK()
{

  //arrange
  var moviecollection = new MovieCollection();
  var httpClientFactoryMock = Substitute.For<IHttpClientFactory>();

  var fakeHttpMessageHandler = new FakeHttpMessageHandler(new HttpResponseMessage() {
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
    Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(moviecollection), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") 
  });
  var fakeHttpClient = new HttpClient(fakeHttpMessageHandler);

  httpClientFactoryMock.CreateClient().Returns(fakeHttpClient);

  // Act
  var service = new Movies(httpClientFactoryMock);
  var result = await service.GetPopularMovies(1);
  //assert
  Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The subject method under test calls

```
 var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("Movie Api");
```

but you configure the mock to return when `CreateClient()` is invoked.

```
httpClientFactoryMock.CreateClient().Returns(fakeHttpClient);
```

which means that when testing and `CreateClient("Movie Api")` is invoked the mock wont know what to do and thus returns *null*, causing the next call to throw NRE

Setup the mock to behave as expected when the system under test is invoked.

```
//...

httpClientFactoryMock.CreateClient("Movie Api").Returns(fakeHttpClient);

//...
```